Do all fragments of an IP packet greater than MTU carry the full PPPoE header when modified in an eBPF tc program?
I hope you are doing well. I am working with eBPF and tc on the egress side to add a PPPoE header to forwarded and locally generated packets. Due to GSO/TSO, I observe packets larger than the MTU size, and I see outputs like skb->gso_size = 1452, skb->gso_segs = 3, skb->len = 4410. My concern is whether the MAC and PPPoE headers, which I inserted in the tc program, will be properly included in each fragment generated by GSO/TSO.
Since fragmentation happens at the IP layer, and PPPoE operates at the link layer, I understand that each fragment should be a complete link layer frame. However, I’m wondering if GSO will replicate the MAC and PPPoE headers in each fragment. If that’s the case, how should I handle the len field of the PPPoE header for each fragment? Or is there a specific approach I should use to ensure that each fragment is correctly processed?
Here’s the eBPF code I’m working with:
SEC("tc")
int pppoe_egress(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
#define BPF_LOG_TOPIC "pppoe_egress"
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;

    u32 pkt_sz = skb->len - 14;
    if (pkt_sz > pppoe_mtu) {
        bpf_log_info("egress package too large size: %u", pkt_sz);
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;
    }

    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)(data);
    if ((void *)(eth + 1) > data_end) {
        bpf_log_info("package size smaller than ethhdr");
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;
    }

    if (eth->h_proto != ETH_IPV4 && eth->h_proto != ETH_IPV6) {
        bpf_log_info("egress eth proto is error: %x", eth->h_proto);
        return TC_ACT_PIPE;
    }

    u32 offset = 14;
    u8 protocol = 0;
    u16 mss_value = 0;
    u16 ppp_proto = ETH_PPP_IPV4;
    // DECAP support since Linux kernel 6.3
    u64 adj_room_flag = BPF_F_ADJ_ROOM_ENCAP_L3_IPV4;
    if (eth->h_proto == ETH_IPV6) {
        ppp_proto = ETH_PPP_IPV6;
        adj_room_flag = BPF_F_ADJ_ROOM_ENCAP_L3_IPV6;

        struct ipv6hdr *iph6;
        if (VALIDATE_READ_DATA(skb, &iph6, offset, sizeof(*iph6))) {
            return TC_ACT_SHOT;
        }
        protocol = iph6->nexthdr;
        offset = offset + 40;
        mss_value = pppoe_mtu - 40 - 20;
    } else {
        struct iphdr *iph;
        if (VALIDATE_READ_DATA(skb, &iph, offset, sizeof(*iph))) {
            return TC_ACT_SHOT;
        }
        protocol = iph->protocol;
        offset = offset + (iph->ihl * 4);
        mss_value = pppoe_mtu - (iph->ihl * 4) - 20;
    }

    if (protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) {
        mss_clamp(skb, offset, mss_value);
    }

    u16 l2_proto = bpf_htons(0x8864);
    bpf_skb_store_bytes(skb, 12, &l2_proto, sizeof(u16), 0);

    int result = bpf_skb_adjust_room(skb, 8, BPF_ADJ_ROOM_MAC, adj_room_flag);
    if (result) {
        bpf_log_info("egress adjust room error %d", result);
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;
    }

    struct pppoe_header pppoe = {
        .version_and_type = 0x11,
        .code = 0x00,
        .session_id = bpf_htons(session_id),
        .length = bpf_htons(pkt_sz + 2),
        .protocol = ppp_proto,
    };

    bpf_skb_store_bytes(skb, sizeof(struct ethhdr), &pppoe, sizeof(struct pppoe_header), 0);
    return TC_ACT_PIPE;
#undef BPF_LOG_TOPIC
}

Any suggestions for handling this properly with tc in such a case? Thank you so much for your help!
Best regards

Fragmentation happens in the IP layer, PPPoE is the link layer. All fragments must be complete link layer frames.

IP packets do not carry PPPoE frames, it is the other way around.

How should I handle the length field of the PPPoE header for each fragment?
